# Why do garbage collectors freeze execution?

Tags: language-agnostic, garbage-collection

I was thinking about garbage collection on the way home, and I began wondering, why does the garbage collector totally freeze execution of a program? Personally I would have designed it to block any threads which try to allocate a new object, but threads which were running would be left alone.
I can't imagine any situation where this would be a problem compared to how a garbage collector currently works.

Comment: I wonder why someone down voted this? Surely it's polite to at least comment on why you're down voting something?

Comment: The downvote is probably because the question makes the dubious assertion that GCs freeze programs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modern garbage collectors (in .NET and Java, anyway) don't actually "stop the world" - they do all kinds of clever things to collect concurrently.

However, you might want to consider a situation like this:

```
 object x = null;
 object y = new object();
 ...
 x = y;
 y = null;
```

Now, suppose the GC looks at `x`, then the lines below the `...` run, and then the GC looks at `y` - it won't have seen any live objects... but the object *should* still be live.

Basically there needs to be a certain amount of pausing in order to get a consistent set of references. Then there's compaction, reference reassignment etc. However, it isn't nearly as bad as it used to be in terms of requiring everything to be stopped for the whole of the GC cycle. It *does*, however, get painful to think about :)

Comment: Ahh ok, as ever the clever chaps at Microsoft are ahead of me. I suspected there was a case like this, I just couldn't quite construct one. Do you know of any good resources (particularly papers which I can view freely) to read up about this?

Comment: Here's one about HotSpot's GC (somewhat old, admittedly): http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11253/

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://blogs.sun.com/theplanetarium/entry/java_vm_trying_a_new and this: http://blogs.sun.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors

Comment: Thankyou, these should keep me entertained for a while ;)

Comment: -1 Firstly, there is no direct correspondence between the source and what the GC acts upon. Secondly, getting a consistent set of references (global roots) does not "require a certain amount of pausing".

Comment: @JonHarrop: I wasn't suggesting a direct correspondence between the source and the GC. I was talking about the GC examining the value of a variable, then some code running, then the GC examining the value of another variable.

Comment: AFAIK objects as such that are referenced inside a *running* method are never collected - or this kind of behavior would be everywhere - but in the end I'm nearly an expert (such as Jon seems to become ;) )

Comment: @CarstenKönig: It depends on the platform. .NET and Java behave differently in this respect. Somewhat shockingly, in .NET if there's an *instance* method running, the "target" of that method call can still be GC'd if it can prove there are no more references to any fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet "Somewhat shockingly". That's exactly what I mean. That observation is only shocking because the mental model your promoting is wrong. There is no direct correlation between scope (e.g. `this` in an instance method) and the roots visible to the GC. In general, its a bad idea to try to reason about source code from the point of view of the garbage collector. The compiler just mutilates it way too much before the GC sees anything.

Comment: @JonHarrop: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. SO comments aren't really the right medium for this discussion, and I know from past discussions with you that we'd have to write an awful lot to make any actual progress here.

Comment: @JonSkeet "I was talking about the GC examining the value of a variable, then some code running, then the GC examining the value of another variable". But variables don't exist in the world of the GC. The GC sees registers, the stack and the heap. The compiler can reorder everything, remove anything, even add stuff before it allocates registers, spills to the stack and heap allocations so it is not possible to reason about what the GC sees and, therefore, what it will do.

Comment: Isn't there some reference counter that GC uses instead (per object)? If so no "pausing" would be needed(?). In this case it's just one object that always has >= 1 ref, thus never considered for GC (if GC has some ref counter it can check).

Comment: @Qtax: Not in any JVM or .NET implementation I'm aware of. Reference counting has problems around cycles, for a start.

Comment: @Qtax You have described what scope-based reference counting (e.g. smart pointers in C++) would do in this case but most GCs use tracing and not reference counting because tracing is faster and handles cycles. Note that tracing and reference counting are duals of each other (one searches for life, the other for death) and David Bacon published a great paper about this called "A unified theory of garbage collection". http://www.research.ibm.com/people/d/dfb/papers/Bacon04Unified.pdf

Comment: @JonSkeet "Not in any JVM or .NET implementation I'm aware of. Reference counting has problems around cycles, for a start". FWIW, some research groups have implemented reference counting collectors using JMTk in the Jikes RVM (e.g. http://grothoff.org/christian/teaching/2007/4705/urc-oopsla-2003.pdf) and reference counting can be augmented with other algorithms (e.g. trial deletion) in order to collect cycles and some languages (e.g. Mathematica and Erlang) evade the problem by permitting only unidirectional heaps so they can use reference counting safely.

Comment: @JonHarrop: Yes, good point. I should have said *production* JVM/.NET implementations.

Answer (score 17):

> I was thinking about garbage collection on the way home, and I began wondering, why does the garbage collector totally freeze execution of a program?

There is a trade-off between latency and throughput in GC design. You can either process heap-allocated blocks individually ("incremental") or you can batch them up and process them all at the same time ("stop the world"). Fully incremental collection never totally freezes a program and it has very low latency but it also has very poor throughput. Stop the world garbage collectors have the worst possible latency (freezing the program for seconds or even minutes at a time) but near-optimal throughput.

All of the major production GCs today provide a middle ground, typically with generational collection with the per-thread nursery generations collected in batches and incremental or concurrent collection of the shared old generation. Thus, only nursery collections incur pauses and nursery size is bounded so pause times are kept low, e.g. 10-100ms in .NET with the workstation GC.

For a simple GC algorithm that never pauses, see [Baker's Treadmill](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/t.html#treadmill). For more information on garbage collection I highly recommend the [Memory Management Reference](http://www.memorymanagement.org/) and the [Garbage Collection Handbook](http://gchandbook.org/).

There is a lot of misinformation in the other answers here. Jon Skeet wrote some source code and started discussing it from the point of view of garbage collection. You need to be very careful doing this because there is little correspondence between source code and what the GC sees. The compiler does instruction block rearrangements, register allocation, promotion and so on, all of which affect what is visible to the GC at run time. In particular, scope in source code is not carried through to compiled code and is typically replaced with the related concept of [liveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis). Jon also wrote that you must pause in order to get the global roots. That is not strictly true although it is the most efficient way to get the global roots and the resulting pause is almost always tiny (sub-millisecond) because you're just copying less than a kB of stack from each thread.

Powerlord wrote that moving collectors must block reads and, therefore, all threads that read. This is also not true. The simplest counter example is immutable data: referential transparency means you can read from any copy safely.

Kico wrote that pauses are required to determine reachability. This is also not true. See Dijkstra's research about "on-the-fly" collectors and any recent real-time GC such as [Stacatto](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-groved/rc24504.pdf).

Jerry Coffin wrote the best answer but moving isn't the reason GCs pause. There are GCs that don't move but do pause (e.g. HLVM's) and those that do move but don't pause (e.g. [Stacatto](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-groved/rc24504.pdf)).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Kico Lobo said, Garbage Collectors can also move things around in memory.

Therefore, they don't just have to block threads that write to memory, but also threads that read from memory.

Which is every thread.

Comment: -1 You can move heap-allocated blocks around without blocking threads.

Answer (score 2):

Most GCs stop execution because objects can move in memory during a collection cycle (at least with most reasonably recent designs). That means either reading or writing almost any object at the wrong time can cause a problem.

There are collectors that have been designed around the idea of just blocking reads (or writes) to the specific parts of memory being modified at a given time, so as long as execution only uses objects that aren't (currently) being moved around, it can proceed unhindered. The problem is that most typical hardware doesn't provide efficient support for this, so even though they work in principle, they're fairly inefficient in practice. There has been at least one attempt at adapting that type of algorithm to use the write protection available in a typical paging unit, but I'm not aware of its having been used for much other than research and experimentation.

The primary alternative is to make the collector *incremental* -- i.e. have it do only a small amount of work at a time, so even though other execution gets stopped, it only has to stop for a little while at any given time.

With multi-core machines becoming so common, however, I'd expect to see more work put into garbage collection algorithms that can run in parallel with other execution. Up until recently, the primary emphasis was on minimizing the total time/effort spent on garbage collection. The growing number of cores available is likely to (often) mean that doing more total work in garbage collection may be easily justified, if doing so allows the mainstream of the code to run with fewer hindrances.

Edit: You might want to read Paul Wilson's [Survey of Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/gcsurvey.ps). This isn't definitive (especially any more, given its age), but it's at least a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the only way it can assure that the refereces it is going to clean are not been used by anyone else.

If it didn´t freezed the execution, it could not assure that.

Comment: why? If an object is holding a reference when the collector scans it, then a reference is held, if it's not holding one when the scan comes along then no reference is held and there is no way it can get a reference back.

Comment: Why do you say "if it's not holding one when the scan comes along then no reference is held and there is no way it can get a reference back"? Look at Jon Skeet's code snippet: x doesn't hold any reference at first, but later it does.

Comment: Indeed, Jon wrote that example after I wrote that comment, he is quite correct.